# How to open a Chome extension Popup using javascript?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to open a Chrome extension popup using content script. I have to open the popup on hovering the links on the web site and pass some content to the popup.

background.js

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if ((request.key == 'info')) {

        sendResponse({ response: request.data });
    }
});
```

content script:

```
$(".xyz").mouseover(function () {
    var message = {
        key: "info",
        data: $(this).html()
    };

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message, function (response) {
        showResponse(response);
    });
});

var showResponse = function (data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data.response));
}
```

In the above code, showResponse method should open the extension popup and I need to update the content with the data.response.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks

Comment: The browserAction popup can be opened only from the background.js listener: chrome.browserAction.openPopup(() => {})

Comment: Thanks. Can you please provide the implementation as I need to open a popup and pass some information to the popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you intend with the popup mechanism of the extension. You *could* implement a popup script as part of your content script.

From the [Mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/openPopup) The extension popup can only be invoked by a specific user action, not programatically. The same applies to chrome but didn't find the explicit statement.

> You can only call this function from inside the handler for a user action,  such as:
>
> Selecting a context menu item defined by the extension.
>
> Activating a keyboard shortcut defined by the extension (note: this is not currently supported in Firefox).
>
> Clicking a button in a page bundled with the extension.